# Routing and Segments

Tags: routes, segments

I'm using the following code for now:

```
Route (in the control panel)
    recipes/{slug} loads _recipes/restaurant

In the template to define the restaurant and list its items
    {% set restaurant = craft.entries.section('restaurants').slug(craft.app.request.getSegment(2)).one() %}
```

How do I change it to {slug}-recipes to make it work?

Advanced routing (in routing file) is preferred for performance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route: `{slug}-recipes`

The in the template:

```
{% set parts = craft.app.request.getSegment(1)|split("-") %}
{% set newslug = parts[0] %}
```

Then you can use: `.slug(newslug)`

Comment: Just tried and getting following error - When using set, you must have the same number of variables and assignments.

Comment: Brad, your edit did the trick. I just changed this part |split("-") to |split("-recipes"). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I never do this before, but maybe it works.

```
return [
  '<value:{slug}>-recipes' =>  ['template' => '_recipes/restaurant'],
]
```

and you can get the value in a template like this :

```
{{value}}
```

Comment: Yes, this approach would work according to the routing docs but it will slow the things down since I can't specify exact channel with entries to look for.